# Compilation error "Failed while installing Dynamic Web Module 2.5"

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I was following https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform#dynamic_web_project and got an error “Failed while installing Dynamic Web Module 2.5” at the very last step.

I checked in my Eclipse error log (.metadata/.log) and I found these stack traces:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.j2ee 4 0 2014-06-25 17:05:18.727 !MESSAGE No
>   IModelProvider exists for project P/MyFrontendProject of version:
>   Dynamic Web Module 2.5 !STACK 0 java.lang.NullPointerException: No
>   IModelProvider exists for project P/MyFrontendProject of version:
>   Dynamic Web Module 2.5 at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.model.ModelProviderManager.getModelProvider(ModelProviderManager.java:101)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.populateDefaultContent(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:284)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.createWeb25DeploymentDescriptor(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:274)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.execute(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:128)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1477)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:441)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$5.run(FacetedProject.java:1099)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChanges(FacetedProject.java:1109)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.commitChanges(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:2020)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.performFinish(ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.java:400)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.internal.wizards.NewProjectDataModelFacetWizard.performFinish(NewProjectDataModelFacetWizard.java:282)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.ModifyFacetedProjectWizard$3.run(ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.java:331)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.ModifyFacetedProjectWizard$4.run(ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.java:345)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core 4 0 2014-06-25
>   17:05:18.934 !MESSAGE Failed while installing Dynamic Web Module 2.5.
>   !STACK 0 java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.populateDefaultContent(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:311)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.createWeb25DeploymentDescriptor(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:274)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web.project.facet.WebFacetInstallDelegate.execute(WebFacetInstallDelegate.java:128)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1477)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:441)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$5.run(FacetedProject.java:1099)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChanges(FacetedProject.java:1109)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.commitChanges(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:2020)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.performFinish(ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.java:400)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.internal.wizards.NewProjectDataModelFacetWizard.performFinish(NewProjectDataModelFacetWizard.java:282)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.ModifyFacetedProjectWizard$3.run(ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.java:331)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.ModifyFacetedProjectWizard$4.run(ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.java:345)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)

I had installed the Web Tools Platform by following these instructions: http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F

That entailed installing these components from the Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development:

Eclipse Java EE Developer Tool
JST Server Adapters Extensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2 features recommended by http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F aren't enough to complete the instructions at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform#dynamic_web_project:

Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
JST Server Adapters Extensions

I found that I also had to add this one:

Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools